# When is a function satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

It is, of course, one of the first results in basic complex analysis that a holomorphic function satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations when considered as a differentiable two-variable real function. I have always seen the converse as: if $f$ is *continuously* differentiable as a function from $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then it is holomorphic (see e.g. Stein and Shakarchi, or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations)). Why is the $C^1$ condition necessary? I don't see where this comes in to the proof below.

Assume that $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continuously differentiable and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Let $h=h_1 + h_2i$. Then
\begin{equation*}
u(x+h_1, y+h_2) - u(x,y) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} h_1 + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}h_2 + o(|h|)
\end{equation*}
and 
\begin{equation*}
v(x+h_1, y+h_2) - v(x,y) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} h_1 + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} h_2 + o(|h|).
\end{equation*}
Multiplying the second equation by $i$ and adding the two together gives 
\begin{align*}
(u+iv)(z+h)-(u+iv)(z) &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} h_1 + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} h_1 + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} h_2 + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} h_2 + o(|h|)\\\
 &= \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \right) (h_1+i h_2) + o(|h|).
\end{align*} 
Now dividing by $h$ gives us the desired result.

Does there exist a differentiable but not $C^1$ function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ which satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations and does NOT correspond to a complex-differentiable function?

Comment: The $C^1$ condition in this proof is used as follows: $C^1 \implies$ (Frechet) differentiable $\implies$ the "directional derivative" local linear approximation dot product formula $[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}]\cdot [h_1,h_2]+o(|h|)$ (see e.g. Theorems 2.17 and 2.19 in Folland's Advanced Calculus)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See [*When is a Function that Satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Equations Analytic?*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2321164) J. D. Gray and S. A. Morris
The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 85, No. 4 (Apr., 1978), pp. 246-256.

Comment: So *that* is why the question's title sounded vaguely familiar... :D

Comment: I wonder if there have been any advancements in the past 44 years since this paper (and 11 years since this answer).

Answer (score 15):

There's also the [Looman–Menchoff theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem).

Comment: Where can I find proof of this theorem?

Comment: @Abhay, see the references in the Wikipedia page

Answer (score 3):

Thinking of the Cauchy-Riemann operator as an elliptic partial differential operator, the basic elliptic regularity result implies that any *distribution* satisfying the C-R equation is a holomorphic function. For example, locally integrable suffices. This result was used in Gunning' "Riemann Surfaces", for example, in the discussion of Serre duality.

Comment: TeX only works inside `$`-signs here. In order to get *italic text* and **bold text** text you can enclose it in single and double asterisks: `*italic text*` and `**bold text**`.

Comment: Just for completeness: $L^p_{\text{loc}}$ suffices for any $p>0$ as proven in http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02807221