# Cauchy-Riemann implies analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is a function satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations holomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15875/when-is-a-function-satisfying-the-cauchy-riemann-equations-holomorphic)

If real the functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations and have continuous partial derivatives in an open set $U$, then the function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $z=x+iy$, is analytic in $U$. Are there less restrictive conditions on $u$ and $v$ to ensure the analyticity of $f$? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There actually are none. One of the more beautiful theorems of Complex Analysis is that a function is holomorphic if and only if it is continuous and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Actually, this answer might be regarded as "less restrictive conditions" since the original question required the partial derivatives to be continuous.