# Function that satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation but not differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for a function that satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation on a whole domain but not differentiable. It seems there are some examples that satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equation on a point (usually the origin) but not differentiable at that point. Or, if the given function satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation on a whole domain, then the function should be analytic?

Edit: The original question is that $\textit{a function f:G$\subset\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is analytic if and only if $\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}f = 0$}$. I found that $\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}f =0$ is equivalent to saying that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation. How can I show that converse of the statement?

Comment: Yes, if C-R equation hold throughout an open set then the function is analytic.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How can I show?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15875/42969

Comment: In my comment above I have to assume continuity of $f$. Otherwise the result is false.

Comment: Hmmm maybe I would change my question